< key > tag in description on GitHub
I wanted to change some release text on my GitHub repository and there is something strange - if I try to add this text < key > - without the spaces to the Editor it is suddenly not visible anymore, and the same happens here on StackOverflow?
How can I enter such text on these sites?

The problem is it gets interpreted as HTML. You can surround it with backticks to label it as literal text: <key> which I typed by having a backtick before the < and another after the >.

Both sites use markdown, see https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/

You can also escape the angle brakets by putting a backslash in front: \<key\> will yield 

ok i will try - but why is this working <key_string>?

The comments here are not full markdown, but the release notes on GitHub and the questions and answers here are, so it's not exactly the same.

The issue: markdown interprets HTML tags
Both GitHub release notes and this site's Q&A text are formatted using markdown syntax, which accepts HTML tags as part of the formatting. Since <key> is valid syntax for a tag, it gets interpreted as such.
Solution: code blocks and escapes
To render <key> in code style, you can use a code block surrounded by backticks:
`<key>`

And to render <key> as regular text, you can escape the angle bracket characters:
\<key\> 

Other similar-looking cases that work
Now, you ask why <key_string> works without escapes, and the answer is that, just like < key >, <key, key>, <123>, <éöç> and other strings with anything but plain ASCII letters between the angle braces, they're not legal HTML tags and thus get rendered as regular text.
Refs
Useful references to learn more about Markdown formatting in general and specifically on StackOverflow and GitHub:

https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/
https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help
https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/getting-started-with-writing-and-formatting-on-github/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax


thanks a lot! But why this is working <key_string> and this not <key>?

@EnsaiTankado See edits.

i see - thanks a lot!
